# What memory cleaner software exactly do?

Tags: memory, software, memory-usage

You must have seen them as applications on mobile devices and I've been using one on mac OS. I was wondering what exactly memory cleaner software do? Do they free up memory in both ROM and RAM? And isn't this something that can be a standard or a must in order to submit apps for public use?

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Your question is a bit vague (what is a "memory cleaner," specifically?), and you're probably posting this on the wrong site.  Software Engineering is a site about the Software Development Life Cycle; your question doesn't seem to have much relevance here.

Comment: How could ROM be freed up? you know what RO stands for, right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I was wondering what exactly memory cleaner software do?

In the best case, they do absolutely nothing. If you're lucky.

Sometimes, they *will* actually free up RAM by deleting caches or forcing processes out of RAM. The thing is: free RAM is actually *bad*. RAM is *much faster* than hard disk, and it is also *much more expensive*. So, you should be using *as much RAM as possible*, not as little as possible. Forcing cached data out of RAM to increase "free RAM" simply means that the data has to be re-loaded again from disk. Memory cleaners slow down your system.

In the worst case, the memory cleaner will use the elevated privileges it requires to do its job to do "other stuff" as well, such as reading your address book and sending it off to be sold to spammers, reading your password database and looking for weak passwords, reading your emails and building a psychological profile, etc.

So, if those programs do nothing in the best case, are bad for performance, and are in the worst case trojans, why do they exist at all? Simple: because people keep installing them.

Writing a memory cleaner is one of the easiest ways of making money by selling software because *the program doesn't even have to do anything*.

Comment: I guess I found my next hobby project to turn me into a millionaire.